# jquery bind issue

Tags: jquery, events, selector, bind

I am setting up a jquery function to bind multiple selectors to multiple events, however it seems to only work for one event but not the other, here is my script:

```js
$('input[id*=_other]').parent().siblings().children().addClass('code');
$('.code, input[id*=_other]').bind('click, keyup', function(){

  $(this).each(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('code')) {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('click')
      }
      else {

      } //not working
    }

    else if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      alert('entered')
    }

    else {

    } //working

  });
});
```

And the html section looks like:

```
<th class="gridlabel">other specify 1<input size="15" tabindex="21" name="q62_5_other" class="other_input" id="q62_5_other" type="text" value="asd"/></th>
    <td headers="q62_header1" class="gridcell"><input tabindex="22" type="radio" name="q62_5" id="q62_5_1" value="1"/></td>
    <td headers="q62_header2" class="gridcell"><input tabindex="23" type="radio" name="q62_5" id="q62_5_2" value="2"/></td>
    <td headers="q62_header3" class="gridcell"><input tabindex="24" type="radio" name="q62_5" id="q62_5_3" value="3"/></td>
    <td headers="q62_header4" class="gridcell"><input tabindex="25" type="radio" name="q62_5" id="q62_5_4" value="4"/></td>
    <td headers="q62_header5" class="gridcell"><input tabindex="26" type="radio" name="q62_5" id="q62_5_5" value="5"/></td>
```

So it is an open text box then followed by 5 radio buttons in table cells, all in one row.

I want the alert "clicked" to come up if any of the 5 radio buttons have been clicked, and alert "entered" to come up if the open text box has been key in.

The alert for the open text box is certainly working, the alert for radio buttons would also work if I only have ".bind('click', function{...", instead of "click" and "keyup".

Not sure how to achieve both scenarios with a modified version of the above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma is not needed. It should be:

```
$('...').bind('click keyup', function() {...});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dfsq, you are quick, and it's working, case solved:)

Answer (score 0):

The comma should not be used... 
Instead of this

```
bind('click, keyup', function(){
```

try this

```
bind('click keyup', function(){
```